# Find all permutations of a 4-letter string that starts with "j" and includes "w"?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, combinations, permutation

I need to find all possible 4-letter combinations that start with "j" and have "w". I can imagine doing it with nested loops, but am sure there is a better way to achieve it with array combination or permutation.

To clarify - I was after permutations (characters can be repeated), as long as it satisfied the criteria -

1) Length - 4 characters.
2) character "j" is the first character.
3) character "w" is present somewhere.

Here is what I tried:

```
w = %w(w)
alphabet = %w(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)

alphabet_permutation = a.permutation(2).to_a.map{|f| f.join()}

three_letters = w.product(alphabet_permutation).map{|f| f.join()}

three_letters.to_a.permutation.map(&:join)
```

P.S. the actual reason for doing  this - trying to remember a 4-letter name of the .com website... Just thought I should actually share this. Now will have to ping all those combinations to see which are actual websites.

Comment: "jwTI", "jBwA" and so on. "w" needs to be present as one 3 characters after "j"

Comment: Can letters be repeated?  Do "jwti" and "Jwti" count as 2 combinations?  If "jwti" and "wjti" are meant to count as one, "combinations" is correct; if they are meant to count as 2, you mean "permuatations".

Comment: "j" has always be the first element, letters can be repeated

Comment: your `w` is irritating..

Comment: You wrote you want combinations, but then you are referring to the order of the letters, which seems like you want permutations. It is contradictory. Which do you want?

Comment: I wonder what's with the down votes?

Comment: I guess I got confused with terminology, sorry. Your answer seems to be the one I need.

Comment: @Stpn it's a not-exactly-useful how-to question with no effort solving it yourself. This could contribute a few votes.

Comment: Man, the downvotes are piling up fast (not mine).  Do you know why?  It's because the your question is vague.  You need to edit-- without delay--to clarify which 4-letter sequences are considered distinct.  I asked you 3 questions; you answered one.

Comment: @JanDvorak I know the rules, just did not want to post some ugly non-working code. I guess people just having bad Saturday or something like that.

Comment: @Stpn posting some ugly non-working code tells us how much you already know. Do post it.

Comment: Not necessarily a bad Saturday.  It's now Sunday in some parts of the world.

Comment: Good edit, Stpn. All too often askers are bombarded with downvotes but do nothing to try to recover.  I'll give you a +1 for responsiveness, but it's also a good question.  I would suggest further clarification.  I understand that characters can be repeated and the order is important (`'jabc'` and `'jbac'` are distinct), but "permutations" refers only to the latter.  Also, you have not clarified how case is to be treated.  By choosing @sawa's answer, I assume case is not important, but that's not clear from the question or the code you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer will give all strings, but includes duplicates when there is more than one `"w"` in a string. I thought that is not a big problem. If it is a problem, then the code needs to be improved.

```
("a".."z").to_a.product(("a".."z").to_a, (1..3).to_a)
.map{|c1, c2, w| "j#{c1}#{c2}".insert(w, "w")}
```

output:

```
["jwaa", "jawa", "jaaw", "jwab", "jawb", "jabw", "jwac", "jawc", "jacw", "jwad", "jawd", "jadw", "jwae", "jawe", "jaew", "jwaf", "jawf", "jafw", "jwag", "jawg", "jagw", "jwah", "jawh", "jahw", "jwai", "jawi", "jaiw", "jwaj", "jawj", "jajw", "jwak", "jawk", "jakw", "jwal", "jawl", "jalw", "jwam", "jawm", "jamw", "jwan", "jawn", "janw", "jwao", "jawo", "jaow", "jwap", "jawp", "japw", "jwaq", "jawq", "jaqw", "jwar", "jawr", "jarw", "jwas", "jaws", "jasw", "jwat", "jawt", "jatw", "jwau", "jawu", "jauw", "jwav", "jawv", "javw", "jwaw", "jaww", "jaww", "jwax", "jawx", "jaxw", "jway", "jawy", "jayw", "jwaz", "jawz", "jazw", "jwba", "jbwa", "jbaw", "jwbb", "jbwb", "jbbw", "jwbc", "jbwc", "jbcw", "jwbd", "jbwd", "jbdw", "jwbe", "jbwe", "jbew", "jwbf", "jbwf", "jbfw", "jwbg", "jbwg", "jbgw", "jwbh", "jbwh", "jbhw", "jwbi", "jbwi", "jbiw", "jwbj", "jbwj", "jbjw", "jwbk", "jbwk", "jbkw", "jwbl", "jbwl", "jblw", "jwbm", "jbwm", "jbmw", "jwbn", "jbwn", "jbnw", "jwbo", "jbwo", "jbow", "jwbp", "jbwp", "jbpw", "jwbq", "jbwq", "jbqw", "jwbr", "jbwr", "jbrw", "jwbs", "jbws", "jbsw", "jwbt", "jbwt", "jbtw", "jwbu", "jbwu", "jbuw", "jwbv", "jbwv", "jbvw", "jwbw", "jbww", "jbww", "jwbx", "jbwx", "jbxw", "jwby", "jbwy", "jbyw", "jwbz", "jbwz", "jbzw", "jwca", "jcwa", "jcaw", "jwcb", "jcwb", "jcbw", "jwcc", "jcwc", "jccw", "jwcd", "jcwd", "jcdw", "jwce", "jcwe", "jcew", "jwcf", "jcwf", "jcfw", "jwcg", "jcwg", "jcgw", "jwch", "jcwh", "jchw", "jwci", "jcwi", "jciw", "jwcj", "jcwj", "jcjw", "jwck", "jcwk", "jckw", "jwcl", "jcwl", "jclw", "jwcm", "jcwm", "jcmw", "jwcn", "jcwn", "jcnw", "jwco", "jcwo", "jcow", "jwcp", "jcwp", "jcpw", "jwcq", "jcwq", "jcqw", "jwcr", "jcwr", "jcrw", "jwcs", "jcws", "jcsw", "jwct", "jcwt", "jctw", "jwcu", "jcwu", "jcuw", "jwcv", "jcwv", "jcvw", "jwcw", "jcww", "jcww", "jwcx", "jcwx", "jcxw", "jwcy", "jcwy", "jcyw", "jwcz", "jcwz", "jczw", "jwda", "jdwa", "jdaw", "jwdb", "jdwb", "jdbw", "jwdc", "jdwc", "jdcw", "jwdd", "jdwd", "jddw", "jwde", "jdwe", "jdew", "jwdf", "jdwf", "jdfw", "jwdg", "jdwg", "jdgw", "jwdh", "jdwh", "jdhw", "jwdi", "jdwi", "jdiw", "jwdj", "jdwj", "jdjw", "jwdk", "jdwk", "jdkw", "jwdl", "jdwl", "jdlw", "jwdm", "jdwm", "jdmw", "jwdn", "jdwn", "jdnw", "jwdo", "jdwo", "jdow", "jwdp", "jdwp", "jdpw", "jwdq", "jdwq", "jdqw", "jwdr", "jdwr", "jdrw", "jwds", "jdws", "jdsw", "jwdt", "jdwt", "jdtw", "jwdu", "jdwu", "jduw", "jwdv", "jdwv", "jdvw", "jwdw", "jdww", "jdww", "jwdx", "jdwx", "jdxw", "jwdy", "jdwy", "jdyw", "jwdz", "jdwz", "jdzw", "jwea", "jewa", "jeaw", "jweb", "jewb", "jebw", "jwec", "jewc", "jecw", "jwed", "jewd", "jedw", "jwee", "jewe", "jeew", "jwef", "jewf", "jefw", "jweg", "jewg", "jegw", "jweh", "jewh", "jehw", "jwei", "jewi", "jeiw", "jwej", "jewj", "jejw", "jwek", "jewk", "jekw", "jwel", "jewl", "jelw", "jwem", "jewm", "jemw", "jwen", "jewn", "jenw", "jweo", "jewo", "jeow", "jwep", "jewp", "jepw", "jweq", "jewq", "jeqw", "jwer", "jewr", "jerw", "jwes", "jews", "jesw", "jwet", "jewt", "jetw", "jweu", "jewu", "jeuw", "jwev", "jewv", "jevw", "jwew", "jeww", "jeww", "jwex", "jewx", "jexw", "jwey", "jewy", "jeyw", "jwez", "jewz", "jezw", "jwfa", "jfwa", "jfaw", "jwfb", "jfwb", "jfbw", "jwfc", "jfwc", "jfcw", "jwfd", "jfwd", "jfdw", "jwfe", "jfwe", "jfew", "jwff", "jfwf", "jffw", "jwfg", "jfwg", "jfgw", "jwfh", "jfwh", "jfhw", "jwfi", "jfwi", "jfiw", "jwfj", "jfwj", "jfjw", "jwfk", "jfwk", "jfkw", "jwfl", "jfwl", "jflw", "jwfm", "jfwm", "jfmw", "jwfn", "jfwn", "jfnw", "jwfo", "jfwo", "jfow", "jwfp", "jfwp", "jfpw", "jwfq", "jfwq", "jfqw", "jwfr", "jfwr", "jfrw", "jwfs", "jfws", "jfsw", "jwft", "jfwt", "jftw", "jwfu", "jfwu", "jfuw", "jwfv", "jfwv", "jfvw", "jwfw", "jfww", "jfww", "jwfx", "jfwx", "jfxw", "jwfy", "jfwy", "jfyw", "jwfz", "jfwz", "jfzw", "jwga", "jgwa", "jgaw", "jwgb", "jgwb", "jgbw", "jwgc", "jgwc", "jgcw", "jwgd", "jgwd", "jgdw", "jwge", "jgwe", "jgew", "jwgf", "jgwf", "jgfw", "jwgg", "jgwg", "jggw", "jwgh", "jgwh", "jghw", "jwgi", "jgwi", "jgiw", "jwgj", "jgwj", "jgjw", "jwgk", "jgwk", "jgkw", "jwgl", "jgwl", "jglw", "jwgm", "jgwm", "jgmw", "jwgn", "jgwn", "jgnw", "jwgo", "jgwo", "jgow", "jwgp", "jgwp", "jgpw", "jwgq", "jgwq", "jgqw", "jwgr", "jgwr", "jgrw", "jwgs", "jgws", "jgsw", "jwgt", "jgwt", "jgtw", "jwgu", "jgwu", "jguw", "jwgv", "jgwv", "jgvw", "jwgw", "jgww", "jgww", "jwgx", "jgwx", "jgxw", "jwgy", "jgwy", "jgyw", "jwgz", "jgwz", "jgzw", "jwha", "jhwa", "jhaw", "jwhb", "jhwb", "jhbw", "jwhc", "jhwc", "jhcw", "jwhd", "jhwd", "jhdw", "jwhe", "jhwe", "jhew", "jwhf", "jhwf", "jhfw", "jwhg", "jhwg", "jhgw", "jwhh", "jhwh", "jhhw", "jwhi", "jhwi", "jhiw", "jwhj", "jhwj", "jhjw", "jwhk", "jhwk", "jhkw", "jwhl", "jhwl", "jhlw", "jwhm", "jhwm", "jhmw", "jwhn", "jhwn", "jhnw", "jwho", "jhwo", "jhow", "jwhp", "jhwp", "jhpw", "jwhq", "jhwq", "jhqw", "jwhr", "jhwr", "jhrw", "jwhs", "jhws", "jhsw", "jwht", "jhwt", "jhtw", "jwhu", "jhwu", "jhuw", "jwhv", "jhwv", "jhvw", "jwhw", "jhww", "jhww", "jwhx", "jhwx", "jhxw", "jwhy", "jhwy", "jhyw", "jwhz", "jhwz", "jhzw", "jwia", "jiwa", "jiaw", "jwib", "jiwb", "jibw", "jwic", "jiwc", "jicw", "jwid", "jiwd", "jidw", "jwie", "jiwe", "jiew", "jwif", "jiwf", "jifw", "jwig", "jiwg", "jigw", "jwih", "jiwh", "jihw", "jwii", "jiwi", "jiiw", "jwij", "jiwj", "jijw", "jwik", "jiwk", "jikw", "jwil", "jiwl", "jilw", "jwim", "jiwm", "jimw", "jwin", "jiwn", "jinw", "jwio", "jiwo", "jiow", "jwip", "jiwp", "jipw", "jwiq", "jiwq", "jiqw", "jwir", "jiwr", "jirw", "jwis", "jiws", "jisw", "jwit", "jiwt", "jitw", "jwiu", "jiwu", "jiuw", "jwiv", "jiwv", "jivw", "jwiw", "jiww", "jiww", "jwix", "jiwx", "jixw", "jwiy", "jiwy", "jiyw", "jwiz", "jiwz", "jizw", "jwja", "jjwa", "jjaw", "jwjb", "jjwb", "jjbw", "jwjc", "jjwc", "jjcw", "jwjd", "jjwd", "jjdw", "jwje", "jjwe", "jjew", "jwjf", "jjwf", "jjfw", "jwjg", "jjwg", "jjgw", "jwjh", "jjwh", "jjhw", "jwji", "jjwi", "jjiw", "jwjj", "jjwj", "jjjw", "jwjk", "jjwk", "jjkw", "jwjl", "jjwl", "jjlw", "jwjm", "jjwm", "jjmw", "jwjn", "jjwn", "jjnw", "jwjo", "jjwo", "jjow", "jwjp", "jjwp", "jjpw", "jwjq", "jjwq", "jjqw", "jwjr", "jjwr", "jjrw", "jwjs", "jjws", "jjsw", "jwjt", "jjwt", "jjtw", "jwju", "jjwu", "jjuw", "jwjv", "jjwv", "jjvw", "jwjw", "jjww", "jjww", "jwjx", "jjwx", "jjxw", "jwjy", "jjwy", "jjyw", "jwjz", "jjwz", "jjzw", "jwka", "jkwa", "jkaw", "jwkb", "jkwb", "jkbw", "jwkc", "jkwc", "jkcw", "jwkd", "jkwd", "jkdw", "jwke", "jkwe", "jkew", "jwkf", "jkwf", "jkfw", "jwkg", "jkwg", "jkgw", "jwkh", "jkwh", "jkhw", "jwki", "jkwi", "jkiw", "jwkj", "jkwj", "jkjw", "jwkk", "jkwk", "jkkw", "jwkl", "jkwl", "jklw", "jwkm", "jkwm", "jkmw", "jwkn", "jkwn", "jknw", "jwko", "jkwo", "jkow", "jwkp", "jkwp", "jkpw", "jwkq", "jkwq", "jkqw", "jwkr", "jkwr", "jkrw", "jwks", "jkws", "jksw", "jwkt", "jkwt", "jktw", "jwku", "jkwu", "jkuw", "jwkv", "jkwv", "jkvw", "jwkw", "jkww", "jkww", "jwkx", "jkwx", "jkxw", "jwky", "jkwy", "jkyw", "jwkz", "jkwz", "jkzw", "jwla", "jlwa", "jlaw", "jwlb", "jlwb", "jlbw", "jwlc", "jlwc", "jlcw", "jwld", "jlwd", "jldw", "jwle", "jlwe", "jlew", "jwlf", "jlwf", "jlfw", "jwlg", "jlwg", "jlgw", "jwlh", "jlwh", "jlhw", "jwli", "jlwi", "jliw", "jwlj", "jlwj", "jljw", "jwlk", "jlwk", "jlkw", "jwll", "jlwl", "jllw", "jwlm", "jlwm", "jlmw", "jwln", "jlwn", "jlnw", "jwlo", "jlwo", "jlow", "jwlp", "jlwp", "jlpw", "jwlq", "jlwq", "jlqw", "jwlr", "jlwr", "jlrw", "jwls", "jlws", "jlsw", "jwlt", "jlwt", "jltw", "jwlu", "jlwu", "jluw", "jwlv", "jlwv", "jlvw", "jwlw", "jlww", "jlww", "jwlx", "jlwx", "jlxw", "jwly", "jlwy", "jlyw", "jwlz", "jlwz", "jlzw", "jwma", "jmwa", "jmaw", "jwmb", "jmwb", "jmbw", "jwmc", "jmwc", "jmcw", "jwmd", "jmwd", "jmdw", "jwme", "jmwe", "jmew", "jwmf", "jmwf", "jmfw", "jwmg", "jmwg", "jmgw", "jwmh", "jmwh", "jmhw", "jwmi", "jmwi", "jmiw", "jwmj", "jmwj", "jmjw", "jwmk", "jmwk", "jmkw", "jwml", "jmwl", "jmlw", "jwmm", "jmwm", "jmmw", "jwmn", "jmwn", "jmnw", "jwmo", "jmwo", "jmow", "jwmp", "jmwp", "jmpw", "jwmq", "jmwq", "jmqw", "jwmr", "jmwr", "jmrw", "jwms", "jmws", "jmsw", "jwmt", "jmwt", "jmtw", "jwmu", "jmwu", "jmuw", "jwmv", "jmwv", "jmvw", "jwmw", "jmww", "jmww", "jwmx", "jmwx", "jmxw", "jwmy", "jmwy", "jmyw", "jwmz", "jmwz", "jmzw", "jwna", "jnwa", "jnaw", "jwnb", "jnwb", "jnbw", "jwnc", "jnwc", "jncw", "jwnd", "jnwd", "jndw", "jwne", "jnwe", "jnew", "jwnf", "jnwf", "jnfw", "jwng", "jnwg", "jngw", "jwnh", "jnwh", "jnhw", "jwni", "jnwi", "jniw", "jwnj", "jnwj", "jnjw", "jwnk", "jnwk", "jnkw", "jwnl", "jnwl", "jnlw", "jwnm", "jnwm", "jnmw", "jwnn", "jnwn", "jnnw", "jwno", "jnwo", "jnow", "jwnp", "jnwp", "jnpw", "jwnq", "jnwq", "jnqw", "jwnr", "jnwr", "jnrw", "jwns", "jnws", "jnsw", "jwnt", "jnwt", "jntw", "jwnu", "jnwu", "jnuw", "jwnv", "jnwv", "jnvw", "jwnw", "jnww", "jnww", "jwnx", "jnwx", "jnxw", "jwny", "jnwy", "jnyw", "jwnz", "jnwz", "jnzw", "jwoa", "jowa", "joaw", "jwob", "jowb", "jobw", "jwoc", "jowc", "jocw", "jwod", "jowd", "jodw", "jwoe", "jowe", "joew", "jwof", "jowf", "jofw", "jwog", "jowg", "jogw", "jwoh", "jowh", "johw", "jwoi", "jowi", "joiw", "jwoj", "jowj", "jojw", "jwok", "jowk", "jokw", "jwol", "jowl", "jolw", "jwom", "jowm", "jomw", "jwon", "jown", "jonw", "jwoo", "jowo", "joow", "jwop", "jowp", "jopw", "jwoq", "jowq", "joqw", "jwor", "jowr", "jorw", "jwos", "jows", "josw", "jwot", "jowt", "jotw", "jwou", "jowu", "jouw", "jwov", "jowv", "jovw", "jwow", "joww", "joww", "jwox", "jowx", "joxw", "jwoy", "jowy", "joyw", "jwoz", "jowz", "jozw", "jwpa", "jpwa", "jpaw", "jwpb", "jpwb", "jpbw", "jwpc", "jpwc", "jpcw", "jwpd", "jpwd", "jpdw", "jwpe", "jpwe", "jpew", "jwpf", "jpwf", "jpfw", "jwpg", "jpwg", "jpgw", "jwph", "jpwh", "jphw", "jwpi", "jpwi", "jpiw", "jwpj", "jpwj", "jpjw", "jwpk", "jpwk", "jpkw", "jwpl", "jpwl", "jplw", "jwpm", "jpwm", "jpmw", "jwpn", "jpwn", "jpnw", "jwpo", "jpwo", "jpow", "jwpp", "jpwp", "jppw", "jwpq", "jpwq", "jpqw", "jwpr", "jpwr", "jprw", "jwps", "jpws", "jpsw", "jwpt", "jpwt", "jptw", "jwpu", "jpwu", "jpuw", "jwpv", "jpwv", "jpvw", "jwpw", "jpww", "jpww", "jwpx", "jpwx", "jpxw", "jwpy", "jpwy", "jpyw", "jwpz", "jpwz", "jpzw", "jwqa", "jqwa", "jqaw", "jwqb", "jqwb", "jqbw", "jwqc", "jqwc", "jqcw", "jwqd", "jqwd", "jqdw", "jwqe", "jqwe", "jqew", "jwqf", "jqwf", "jqfw", "jwqg", "jqwg", "jqgw", "jwqh", "jqwh", "jqhw", "jwqi", "jqwi", "jqiw", "jwqj", "jqwj", "jqjw", "jwqk", "jqwk", "jqkw", "jwql", "jqwl", "jqlw", "jwqm", "jqwm", "jqmw", "jwqn", "jqwn", "jqnw", "jwqo", "jqwo", "jqow", "jwqp", "jqwp", "jqpw", "jwqq", "jqwq", "jqqw", "jwqr", "jqwr", "jqrw", "jwqs", "jqws", "jqsw", "jwqt", "jqwt", "jqtw", "jwqu", "jqwu", "jquw", "jwqv", "jqwv", "jqvw", "jwqw", "jqww", "jqww", "jwqx", "jqwx", "jqxw", "jwqy", "jqwy", "jqyw", "jwqz", "jqwz", "jqzw", "jwra", "jrwa", "jraw", "jwrb", "jrwb", "jrbw", "jwrc", "jrwc", "jrcw", "jwrd", "jrwd", "jrdw", "jwre", "jrwe", "jrew", "jwrf", "jrwf", "jrfw", "jwrg", "jrwg", "jrgw", "jwrh", "jrwh", "jrhw", "jwri", "jrwi", "jriw", "jwrj", "jrwj", "jrjw", "jwrk", "jrwk", "jrkw", "jwrl", "jrwl", "jrlw", "jwrm", "jrwm", "jrmw", "jwrn", "jrwn", "jrnw", "jwro", "jrwo", "jrow", "jwrp", "jrwp", "jrpw", "jwrq", "jrwq", "jrqw", "jwrr", "jrwr", "jrrw", "jwrs", "jrws", "jrsw", "jwrt", "jrwt", "jrtw", "jwru", "jrwu", "jruw", "jwrv", "jrwv", "jrvw", "jwrw", "jrww", "jrww", "jwrx", "jrwx", "jrxw", "jwry", "jrwy", "jryw", "jwrz", "jrwz", "jrzw", "jwsa", "jswa", "jsaw", "jwsb", "jswb", "jsbw", "jwsc", "jswc", "jscw", "jwsd", "jswd", "jsdw", "jwse", "jswe", "jsew", "jwsf", "jswf", "jsfw", "jwsg", "jswg", "jsgw", "jwsh", "jswh", "jshw", "jwsi", "jswi", "jsiw", "jwsj", "jswj", "jsjw", "jwsk", "jswk", "jskw", "jwsl", "jswl", "jslw", "jwsm", "jswm", "jsmw", "jwsn", "jswn", "jsnw", "jwso", "jswo", "jsow", "jwsp", "jswp", "jspw", "jwsq", "jswq", "jsqw", "jwsr", "jswr", "jsrw", "jwss", "jsws", "jssw", "jwst", "jswt", "jstw", "jwsu", "jswu", "jsuw", "jwsv", "jswv", "jsvw", "jwsw", "jsww", "jsww", "jwsx", "jswx", "jsxw", "jwsy", "jswy", "jsyw", "jwsz", "jswz", "jszw", "jwta", "jtwa", "jtaw", "jwtb", "jtwb", "jtbw", "jwtc", "jtwc", "jtcw", "jwtd", "jtwd", "jtdw", "jwte", "jtwe", "jtew", "jwtf", "jtwf", "jtfw", "jwtg", "jtwg", "jtgw", "jwth", "jtwh", "jthw", "jwti", "jtwi", "jtiw", "jwtj", "jtwj", "jtjw", "jwtk", "jtwk", "jtkw", "jwtl", "jtwl", "jtlw", "jwtm", "jtwm", "jtmw", "jwtn", "jtwn", "jtnw", "jwto", "jtwo", "jtow", "jwtp", "jtwp", "jtpw", "jwtq", "jtwq", "jtqw", "jwtr", "jtwr", "jtrw", "jwts", "jtws", "jtsw", "jwtt", "jtwt", "jttw", "jwtu", "jtwu", "jtuw", "jwtv", "jtwv", "jtvw", "jwtw", "jtww", "jtww", "jwtx", "jtwx", "jtxw", "jwty", "jtwy", "jtyw", "jwtz", "jtwz", "jtzw", "jwua", "juwa", "juaw", "jwub", "juwb", "jubw", "jwuc", "juwc", "jucw", "jwud", "juwd", "judw", "jwue", "juwe", "juew", "jwuf", "juwf", "jufw", "jwug", "juwg", "jugw", "jwuh", "juwh", "juhw", "jwui", "juwi", "juiw", "jwuj", "juwj", "jujw", "jwuk", "juwk", "jukw", "jwul", "juwl", "julw", "jwum", "juwm", "jumw", "jwun", "juwn", "junw", "jwuo", "juwo", "juow", "jwup", "juwp", "jupw", "jwuq", "juwq", "juqw", "jwur", "juwr", "jurw", "jwus", "juws", "jusw", "jwut", "juwt", "jutw", "jwuu", "juwu", "juuw", "jwuv", "juwv", "juvw", "jwuw", "juww", "juww", "jwux", "juwx", "juxw", "jwuy", "juwy", "juyw", "jwuz", "juwz", "juzw", "jwva", "jvwa", "jvaw", "jwvb", "jvwb", "jvbw", "jwvc", "jvwc", "jvcw", "jwvd", "jvwd", "jvdw", "jwve", "jvwe", "jvew", "jwvf", "jvwf", "jvfw", "jwvg", "jvwg", "jvgw", "jwvh", "jvwh", "jvhw", "jwvi", "jvwi", "jviw", "jwvj", "jvwj", "jvjw", "jwvk", "jvwk", "jvkw", "jwvl", "jvwl", "jvlw", "jwvm", "jvwm", "jvmw", "jwvn", "jvwn", "jvnw", "jwvo", "jvwo", "jvow", "jwvp", "jvwp", "jvpw", "jwvq", "jvwq", "jvqw", "jwvr", "jvwr", "jvrw", "jwvs", "jvws", "jvsw", "jwvt", "jvwt", "jvtw", "jwvu", "jvwu", "jvuw", "jwvv", "jvwv", "jvvw", "jwvw", "jvww", "jvww", "jwvx", "jvwx", "jvxw", "jwvy", "jvwy", "jvyw", "jwvz", "jvwz", "jvzw", "jwwa", "jwwa", "jwaw", "jwwb", "jwwb", "jwbw", "jwwc", "jwwc", "jwcw", "jwwd", "jwwd", "jwdw", "jwwe", "jwwe", "jwew", "jwwf", "jwwf", "jwfw", "jwwg", "jwwg", "jwgw", "jwwh", "jwwh", "jwhw", "jwwi", "jwwi", "jwiw", "jwwj", "jwwj", "jwjw", "jwwk", "jwwk", "jwkw", "jwwl", "jwwl", "jwlw", "jwwm", "jwwm", "jwmw", "jwwn", "jwwn", "jwnw", "jwwo", "jwwo", "jwow", "jwwp", "jwwp", "jwpw", "jwwq", "jwwq", "jwqw", "jwwr", "jwwr", "jwrw", "jwws", "jwws", "jwsw", "jwwt", "jwwt", "jwtw", "jwwu", "jwwu", "jwuw", "jwwv", "jwwv", "jwvw", "jwww", "jwww", "jwww", "jwwx", "jwwx", "jwxw", "jwwy", "jwwy", "jwyw", "jwwz", "jwwz", "jwzw", "jwxa", "jxwa", "jxaw", "jwxb", "jxwb", "jxbw", "jwxc", "jxwc", "jxcw", "jwxd", "jxwd", "jxdw", "jwxe", "jxwe", "jxew", "jwxf", "jxwf", "jxfw", "jwxg", "jxwg", "jxgw", "jwxh", "jxwh", "jxhw", "jwxi", "jxwi", "jxiw", "jwxj", "jxwj", "jxjw", "jwxk", "jxwk", "jxkw", "jwxl", "jxwl", "jxlw", "jwxm", "jxwm", "jxmw", "jwxn", "jxwn", "jxnw", "jwxo", "jxwo", "jxow", "jwxp", "jxwp", "jxpw", "jwxq", "jxwq", "jxqw", "jwxr", "jxwr", "jxrw", "jwxs", "jxws", "jxsw", "jwxt", "jxwt", "jxtw", "jwxu", "jxwu", "jxuw", "jwxv", "jxwv", "jxvw", "jwxw", "jxww", "jxww", "jwxx", "jxwx", "jxxw", "jwxy", "jxwy", "jxyw", "jwxz", "jxwz", "jxzw", "jwya", "jywa", "jyaw", "jwyb", "jywb", "jybw", "jwyc", "jywc", "jycw", "jwyd", "jywd", "jydw", "jwye", "jywe", "jyew", "jwyf", "jywf", "jyfw", "jwyg", "jywg", "jygw", "jwyh", "jywh", "jyhw", "jwyi", "jywi", "jyiw", "jwyj", "jywj", "jyjw", "jwyk", "jywk", "jykw", "jwyl", "jywl", "jylw", "jwym", "jywm", "jymw", "jwyn", "jywn", "jynw", "jwyo", "jywo", "jyow", "jwyp", "jywp", "jypw", "jwyq", "jywq", "jyqw", "jwyr", "jywr", "jyrw", "jwys", "jyws", "jysw", "jwyt", "jywt", "jytw", "jwyu", "jywu", "jyuw", "jwyv", "jywv", "jyvw", "jwyw", "jyww", "jyww", "jwyx", "jywx", "jyxw", "jwyy", "jywy", "jyyw", "jwyz", "jywz", "jyzw", "jwza", "jzwa", "jzaw", "jwzb", "jzwb", "jzbw", "jwzc", "jzwc", "jzcw", "jwzd", "jzwd", "jzdw", "jwze", "jzwe", "jzew", "jwzf", "jzwf", "jzfw", "jwzg", "jzwg", "jzgw", "jwzh", "jzwh", "jzhw", "jwzi", "jzwi", "jziw", "jwzj", "jzwj", "jzjw", "jwzk", "jzwk", "jzkw", "jwzl", "jzwl", "jzlw", "jwzm", "jzwm", "jzmw", "jwzn", "jzwn", "jznw", "jwzo", "jzwo", "jzow", "jwzp", "jzwp", "jzpw", "jwzq", "jzwq", "jzqw", "jwzr", "jzwr", "jzrw", "jwzs", "jzws", "jzsw", "jwzt", "jzwt", "jztw", "jwzu", "jzwu", "jzuw", "jwzv", "jzwv", "jzvw", "jwzw", "jzww", "jzww", "jwzx", "jzwx", "jzxw", "jwzy", "jzwy", "jzyw", "jwzz", "jzwz", "jzzw"]
```

Comment: Did you really have to include the whole output in the answer? Why?

Comment: To confirm this is actually what the OP wanted. The question was not that clear.

Comment: Great, that's what I was after thank you! Will accept answer in a minute

Comment: @sawa it could have been a misclick. Trying to touch-scroll, trying to get a full breakdown of the votes, trying to provoke you into saying an offense...

Comment: @Jan, sawa cannot be provoked :-).

Comment: Not at problem, w can be repeated

Comment: I mean strings like `"jwwa"` is included more than once in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question and decided to solve it. My method was a little different than Sawa's so I thought I'd share it.

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
alphabet.permutation(4).to_a.select{|x|x.first.eql?('j') && x.include?('w')}
```

I won't post the output, because it's really long! running count on the above method gives 1656 results!